# AC LC Filter for a Solenoid - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: filter, inductor, solenoid

I've been working on a circuit that uses a microcontroller and an H-bridge with 34VDC supply to control a variety of low voltage loads including 24VAC solenoids at 50/60Hz ([SHEPWM waveform](https://ojs.unsw.adfa.edu.au/index.php/juer/article/viewFile/974/604) to knock down harmonics) and 12VDC (classic PWM waveform @ 500Hz switching frequency).

The classic PWM is working fine, no mystery there. Where I am struggling is how to properly design a filter that will create a (more or less) smooth AC signal for the 24VAC solenoids. The 24VAC solenoids are assumed to have inductance of 100mH and 200mH in the on and off state, respectively. My starting point was to use an LC filter as shown in the attached reference schematic.

To get some clue about what is going on (instead of merely guessing) I created the [attached LTSpice model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDQgYdTk0UwnsCejf-KR1UAtPDNHmQ_G/view?usp=sharing). It treats the H-bridge as a voltage source switching between +34VDC and 0VDC in the top half of the AC cycle and between 0VDC and -34VDC in the bottom half. The nominal resistance of the H-bridge is accounted for. In simulation I am able to adjust L and C values to get a decent sinusoidal waveform for the solenoid, but in real life the o-scope (and the chatter of the solenoid) is showing a very different story - it's pretty much scrambled and there appears to be some ghosting up to around 70VDC.

The following two images are measured from GND to the lower side of the inductor in the following setup (ignore the value of the inductor in the diagram):
[image]

This is with a 50uF capacitance (5 parallel 10uF/50V capacitors) and three 1mH inductors in series
[image: O-scope readout]

and this is the same setup with only about 500uH of inductance;
[image]

So far I have tried the following:

- Adding bulk capacitance to the 34VDC supply (electrolytic, up to 470uF) to deal with the current spikes
- Various values for the inductor L ranging from 330uH to 1000uH, and even 3x 1000uH in series
- Various values for the capacitor C ranging from 10uF to 470uF, bipolar electrolytic type
- Various values for the capacitor C ranging from 10uF to 5x 10uF in parallel, MLCC type

Can anyone suggest possible directions to explore to get the desired sinusoidal output? Do I need to use a different type of inductor or capacitor? Do I need to look at another filter type like LCL or something else altogether? What's bogus about the LTspice model?

Comment: I can't find the link of SHEPWM24VAC.txt, in your LTSpice model

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ab_b4ExC28zGtJe-SQijTHfFniRl8okL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: delete all the text lines of code

Comment: What do you hope to see by measuring the voltage between GND and one end of the solenoid? Why not *across* the solenoid, since that's where you apply the filter?

Comment: I would measure across the solenoid, but I am not about to go clip the GND wire of my scope to one side of the solenoid... bad things happen that way. Got a better way to measure?